# sharepoint 2013 app create list in host web

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

Right now I have a SharePoint-hosted app and and list in it, so right now the app and list are deployed in the Web host, how can I make so my list are deployed in the Host web?

UPDATE

> Failed to get hos web title, Error: The field or the propertie Appbokning does not exist
>
> Failed to Create the list. Passing in an empty or null value of parameter strTitle

```
$(document).ready(function () {
getHostWebProperties();
createlist();
event.preventDefault();
});

function getHostWebProperties() {
    var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentcontext, hostUrl);
    var hostweb = hostcontext.get_web();
    currentcontext.load(hostweb, "Appbokning");
    // "Appbokning" is my title of my host web
    currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(
                        function () {
                            alert("The title of the host web of this app is " + hostweb.get_title());

                        },
                        function(sender, args) {
                            alert('Failed to get host web title. Error:' + args.get_message());


                        }
                    );
}



function createlist() {
    var web = context.get_web();
    // Create an announcement SharePoint list with the name that the user specifies.
    var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentcontext, hostUrl);
    var hostweb = hostcontext.get_web();
    var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    var list = web.get_lists();
    var listTitle;
    
    listTitle = list.getByTitle("AppbokningarList");
    // this is my listname that i have i VS, based on a calenderlist
    listCreationInfo.set_title(listTitle);
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.calendar);
    var lists = hostweb.get_lists();
    var newList = lists.add(listCreationInfo);
    context.load(newList);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onListCreationSuccess, onListCreationFail);
}

function onListCreationSuccess() {
    alert('List created successfully!');
}

function onListCreationFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to create the list. ' + args.get_message());
}


function getQueryStringParameter(param) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == param) {
            return singleParam[1];
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The app needs to be given `Manage` Permissions on the `Host Web` in order to create a list in it.  The context of the host web is retrieved by passing context of the app web and host url to `SP.AppContextSite`. Here is a code sample to create a list in `Host Web`.

```
function createlist() {
    // Create an announcement SharePoint list with the name that the user specifies.
    var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentcontext, hostUrl);
    var hostweb = hostcontext.get_web();
    var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    var listTitle = document.getElementById("createList").value;
    listCreationInfo.set_title(listTitle);
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.announcements);
    var lists = hostweb.get_lists();
    var newList = lists.add(listCreationInfo);
    context.load(newList);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onListCreationSuccess, onListCreationFail);
}

function onListCreationSuccess() {
    alert('List created successfully!');
}

function onListCreationFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to create the list. ' + args.get_message());
}
```

See this for more info: http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2013/12/sharepoint-2013-apps-access-data-in.html

**UPDATE**

Answer based on the updated question.

```
`currentcontext.load(hostweb, "Appbokning");`
```

should be replaced with `currentcontext.load(hostweb, "Title");`. Moreover, if you want to create a Calendar list in host web named "AppbokningarList", simply replace

```
var listTitle;
listTitle = list.getByTitle("AppbokningarList");
```

with `var listTitle = "AppbokningarList";`

Comment: alright, how i do set permissions the apps on the host-web? Do u mean in the Appmanifest?

Comment: Yes AppManifest, App properties -> Permissions -> Content -> Web.

Comment: Yes i have "Read" there..

Comment: What should i add here ? var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));

Comment: It is a function which returns the host web url: `function getQueryStringParameter(param) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");    
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == param) {
            return singleParam[1];
    }   
    }
}`

Comment: Alright, thanks i will update my code now in the top so u can se what my Erros are.

Comment: Alright have done like that now, in my app permission the web permission is Read, but i get this error, Falited to create the list. Access Denied. You dont have the rights to complete this action, also my getQueryStringParameter(param) says Not all code paths return a value

Comment: You need to give Manage permissions in order to create a list.

Comment: Alright i have another problem, how do i create a calender list? SP.ListTemplateType.calender, this is not a valid template, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listtemplatetype

Comment: Use `SP.ListTemplateType.events`

Comment: Thanks man :) how could i check if the list exist dont create but if i dont exist create it

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40828/how-to-verify-in-javascript-object-model-if-a-list-exists. Check the answer by @Vadim