# SharepointList or List created inside VS2013 better while creating SPhostedapp

Tags: list

Developing a SPHostedApp for registering (petty)incomes and store it in a list programatically. May I know the best option : whether to create manually a SPcustom list and then write code that inserts rows into it **or** create a list inside the VSproject and store there? This app may be used later to be used in different client SP sites. Also this app needs to be installed and uninstalled easily any item. In that case will I lose the data earlier entered? TIA

Answer (score 2):

The list which will store the data should be packaged inside the Add-in (App). So the best practice is to create the list through the Add-in and not manually.
Now another consideration for you is where should be this list located.

1. **List in App Web:** The list will be created in the Add-ins web. So when the Add-in is uninstalled , whole data will be lost.You can create list decalratively.Follow this [post](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/sharepoint-list-in-sharepoint-hosted-app.html).
2. **List in Host Web :** List is created in the site where the Add-in is installed. Data will be preserved even after Add-in is uninstalled.You cannot create list in host web declaratively, you will have to write JSOM to create list. Follow this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122083/sharepoint-2013-app-create-list-in-host-web). 
   Make sure you give App `Manage` permission on host web in this case.